# Splitting an array into n arrays which are close to eqaul of elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to split an array into n arrays that are close to equal elements.
It's cards game so the difference in elements in the last one max should be 1 or 2

```js
const splitArray = (arr, n) => {

    if (n < 2) {
        return arr
    }
    let size;
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if (arr.length % n === 0) {
            size = arr.length / n
            while (i < arr.length) {
                result.push(arr.slice(i, i += size))
            }
        } else {
            while (i < arr.length) {
                size = Math.floor(arr.length / n)
                result.push(arr.slice(i, i += size))
            }
        }
    }
    return result
}

console.log(splitArray(shuffled, 7).length)
console.log(splitArray(shuffled, 7))
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: my code gives me non equal arrays. the last one has less number of elements by 4 of 5